# Install R on UBUNTU 13.10

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

How can I install R on UBUNTU 13.10? If I use apt-get, the package will not be found:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package r-base
E: Unable to locate package r-base-dev
```

or:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Why would one want to do that? You bypass an important piece of the security concept of your system. Why risk that? Why not add a repository that provides the packages you want to install?

Comment: Because the packages are not found.. for my Ubuntu version.

Comment: Look at [this README on every CRAN mirror](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu) and also try to fix line 57 in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel R Ubuntu packages for Raring & Saucy aren't in CRAN mirrors since they aren't in LTS status

Comment: Good point, thanks @hrbmstr.  I always remain current, so maybe for those insisting on outdated OS version, there is indeed no other solution apart from ... locally re-building the .deb files.  I'd upgrade.

Comment: Def agree with Dirk. Unless you are forced by your org to be on 13.10, upgrading wld be my first suggestion. If not that, then grab the sources and build with the options used by the other Ubuntu packages. That will be waaaay more constant work in the end, though.